# How to Import ParseLoginUI on Android?

Tags: java, android, import, android-studio, parse-platform

I am following the guide here: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui-login

I have downloaded the ParseLoginUI library here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

I have added the following code into my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity 
      android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:launchMode="singleTop">
      <meta-data 
      android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED" 
      android:value="true"/>
 </activity>
```

In order to cause the compiler (Android Studio) to recognize `com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity` I have gone to `file>import module` and chosen the ParseLoginUI module, added the requisite Version 21 Android libraries, and relaunched the project.

Android Studio still fails to "see" ParseLoginUI for the purposes of `com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity`.

If I go to `Open Module Settings>Dependencies` and add it, I get the following dexDebug error on Run (for having redefinitions of the same things I assume, as I am already importing Bolts and the base Parse library):

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /home/self/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-21.0.0-84fe27c84620d9d1d0366e677d39187958cdeae2.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-59201b957d56890fa572d9b50512a6f2fdbf8328.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/bolts-android-1.1.4-9ea2b78f62b6675997357b28f74799123765c89e.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/internal_impl-21.0.0-e68dd2a2fa83b4ca8fc033e2ef13aa6564c28f93.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-b289af4931246cca9970de0d8e83c2176e39f30a.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-cb1bcbce9da5b04995ce21b5c19d40f50ba8334f.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/Parse-1.8.0-80975c368a2c79be790656f7b067b4aa0a95d934.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/Parse-1.8.0-927d9278af7e6a3c6499384dd13c64496c52f520.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-b2bc14c219454432091558890ad02e61658d0b64.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/guava-18.0-c7df0a658a5a733f4cbfaaf52684d55dd56d60ca.jar /home/self/Documents/AppTest/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-8d007e2d2791d788153c8e9792f20e99091e80fa.jar
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/ParseAuthenticationProvider;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue

> Android Studio still fails to "see" ParseLoginUI for the purposes of com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.

I resolved this by right clicking on my project -> Open Module Settings -> selected my app -> then select Dependencies.  I then added ParseLoginUI as a dependency, and rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

That's multi dex exception:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files
```

It arises with couple reasons, one of the reason is you might have referenced the same library in each modules and a project.